# How to update the display while still in a function (iOS with MonoTouch/Xamarin)

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, overlay, xamarin, interactive

I have a process that queries information and I want to display it on the screen as it is being received in my UIViewController.  What I want to do is to use an overlay like this one

https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/MWC/MWC.iOS/UI/Controls/LoadingOverlay.cs

and update `loadingLabel.Text` from the UIViewController.  However, adding this view doesn't seem to make it work instantly - i'm guessing that I need the function call to exit before the graphics are updated.

What is the methodology to allow me to display this type of overlay, and have it "run" while I process data?  Do I need to move the calls to a separate thread and update the display through delegate functions?

Answer (score 2):

After re-reading and Jason's comment you probably want to do something like the following:

```cs
        Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {

            //Do Process intensive things here

            for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                this.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                                        {
                    this.MyLabel.Text == string.Format("Counted to {0}", i);
                });
            }
        });
```

Basically whenever you want to update the UI you need to do it on the Main Thread.

Comment: It's currently all in the UIViewController thread.  Do I need to move the relevant code to a background thread in order to have real-time data update on the display?

Comment: Yes, you need to run any blocking operation on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

For UIKit to update the screen, your code needs to run the main loop.   The easy way to run the main loop is to run some code and return control, so the existing loop runs and handles your events (timers, input, display changes).

There are a few things that you can do:

- Run any blocking operations on the background, and then update the UI by using InvokeOnMainThread.    This means that your app is always running the main loop, but every once in a while, a background thread requests that some code is executed (like displaying a status).
- Manually run the main loop in the middle of your application.   This is not really a good idea, but can work on some very limited cases.   See my answer in this question: [UIAlertView does not wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882075/uialertview-does-not-wait/4807745#4807745)

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford running Xamarin.iOS from the Alpha channel, you have access to C#5 async/await. It nicely hide the tasks and callbacks complexity.

```cs
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    muButton.TouchUpInside += DoSomething;
}

async void DoSomething (object o, EventArge e)
{
    myLabel.Text = "Starting";
    for (var i = 0; i<10;i++)
    {
        await ProcessPart(i);
        myLabel.Text = String.Format ("Progress : {i}0%", i+1);
    }

    myLabel.Text = "Done";
}

Task ProcessPart (int i)
{
    Task.Delay (1000);
}
```

If your processing is smart enough to report its own progress, you could change it's signature to `IEnumerable<Task<int>> Process ()` and have a nice refresh loop like:

```cs
async void DoSomething (object o, EventArge e)
{
    foreach (var tp in Process())
        myLabel.Text = String.Format ("Progress : {i}0%", await tp +1);
}
```

A dummy Process() function could look like:

```cs
IEnumerable<Task<int>> Process ()
{
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
        yield return Task.Delay (1000).ContinueWith(x => i);
}
```